# Removing iphone4 & 4s from supported devices in app

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, app-store-connect, iphone-4

Is there a way to support only iphone5 and above in your app?

Is it an xcode settings thing?  When I submitted our app it says you need screenshots for iphone 4 since your binary supports it.

I am using spritekit and building with ios 8.1 . Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: What app devs are doing is to mention this in the app description (ie Warning: this app has not been optimized for iPhone 4 devices. You may experience lag, etc etc).

Comment: You can remove iPhone 4 be specifying minimal os to iOS 8, but this is not apply for iPhone 4s

Answer (score 2):

you cannot remove support for a device that Apple still supports on the App Store.  You need to build your app to be compatible with all iPhones that Apple wants to support on the App Store.